# pooled cross section data

Tags: least-squares, survey, cross-section, elasticity

I want to find input demand elasticities using a cost function. Input quantities and input prices are available for individual farmers for  5 food crops and 5 years (2015-2019). But farmers may vary across the time. I wanted to increase the sample size and then I pool the data of 5years then the total number of observations are 1200. My supervisor advised me to consider the 5 crops as one crop since theses crops are mostly showed similar in cost of production.
Could I perform pool OLS If I take real values of the data?  I didn’t notice empirical evidence to follow.